# How to correctly implement kmalloc using C?

Tags: c, qemu, xv6, kmalloc

I have implemented *kmalloc* in the *Makefile, defs.h, kmalloc.c, sysproc.c, usys.S, syscall.h, and syscall.c*. I have a test case called *test_1.c* to test my implementation of *kmalloc*. I took the source code from xv6, I applied my implementations and changes, then run it on qemu.

I execute *./test-mmap.sh* to know if I pass the test case. Turns out I didn't pass, I got error : "*test_1.c: error: implicit declaration function of kmalloc*". But I have implemented the *kmalloc* correctly and in the correct files. I am confuse, what am I missing here?

Comment: You don't need all your code to create a [mre]. Here's a reproducible example: `int main(void) { void* addr = kmalloc(2000); }` - nothing more is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When compiling `test.c` the compiler (pre-processor) includes these files:

```
#include "param.h"
#include "types.h"
#include "stat.h"
#include "user.h"
#include "fs.h"
#include "fcntl.h"
#include "syscall.h"
#include "traps.h"
#include "memlayout.h"
```

None of those files have an **explicit** declaration for `kmalloc()`, so the compiler complains about an **implicit** declaration of `kmalloc()` when it sees it at line 18.

There is an explicit declaration for `kmalloc()` in `defs.h` (at line 81), but that file isn't included by `test.c` so the compiler has no idea it exists.

To solve this problem, either add `#include "defs.h"` at the top of `test1.c` or in something that is already included by `test1.c` (e.g. maybe at the top of `syscall.h`); or add an explicit declaration ("`void* kmalloc(uint);`") at the top of `test1.c` or in something that is already included by `test.c`.

Note that depending on how you solve the problem you may (or may not) end up with an "implicit declaration of kfree()" problem next; which can be solved in the same way.